# Wso2esb Transaction for local Database

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am really worrying about this future.If your developing some product like middleware you should aware of all the future like transaction,sec,.etc
security is good in wso2 where as transactions are really poor 
i am using wso2esb4.8.0 and wso2dss3.0.1 .I wish to insert the data into my 2 tables simple logic if my 2nd table went wrong my  first table also roll backed.For this i used wso2dss **Box-carring** future and its perfectly fine while i am doing from wso2dss try-it .BUt same future i wish to incorporate with wso2esb .i call 4 operation like beginboxcarring,insertintot1,insertintot2,endboxcarring  but its not working in this then i got sloution with get JSESSIONID which will create when call a beginboxcarring but there is no use i tried with this properties to get JSESSIONID
and my proxy is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="TransactionProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="M1" value="*************HITTING Transaction PROXY*************"/>
         </log>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <property name="companycode" expression="//companycode/text()"/>
         <property name="companyname" expression="//companyname/text()"/>
         <property name="clientcode" expression="//clientcode/text()"/>
         <property name="clientname" expression="//clientname/text()"/>
         <property name="session type"
                   value="JSESSIONID"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                                 xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                  <soapenv:Header/>
                  <soapenv:Body/>
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="M2" value="*************HITTING Transaction PROXY*************"/>
         </log>
         <header name="Action" value="urn:begin_boxcar"/>
         <property name="setCookieHeader"
                   expression="$trp:Set-Cookie"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <callout serviceURL="http://localhosttt:9764/services/Transaction/begin_boxcar"
                  action="urn:begin_boxcar">
            <source type="envelope"/>
            <target xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                    xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
         </callout>
         <property name="setCookieHeader"
                   expression="$trp:Set-Cookie"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="JSESSIONID" expression="get-property('setCookieHeader')"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <p:insertinto_mclient_OP xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                  <xs:clientcode xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:clientcode>
                  <xs:clientname xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:clientname>
                  <xs:createdbyid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">-1</xs:createdbyid>
                  <xs:modifiedbyid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">-1</xs:modifiedbyid>
               </p:insertinto_mclient_OP>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('clientcode')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('clientname')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <header name="Action" value="urn:insertinto_mclient_OP"/>
         <callout serviceURL="http://localhosttt:9764/services/Transaction/"
                  action="urn:insertinto_mclient_OP">
            <source xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                    xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
            <target xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                    xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
         </callout>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <p:insertinto_mcompany_OP xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                  <xs:companycode xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:companycode>
                  <xs:comapnyname xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:comapnyname>
                  <xs:createdbyid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">-1</xs:createdbyid>
                  <xs:modifiedbyid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">-1</xs:modifiedbyid>
                  <xs:clientid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">-1</xs:clientid>
               </p:insertinto_mcompany_OP>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('companycode')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('companyname')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="M5" value="**************hitting2nd dss*****"/>
         </log>
         <header name="Action" value="urn:insertinto_mcompany_OP"/>
         <callout serviceURL="http://localhosttt:9764/services/Transaction/"
                  action="urn:insertinto_mcompany_OP">
            <source xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                    xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
            <target xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                    xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
         </callout>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                                 xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                  <soapenv:Header/>
                  <soapenv:Body/>
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="M3" value="*************HITTING Transaction PROXY*************"/>
         </log>
         <header name="Action" value="urn:end_boxcar"/>
         <callout serviceURL="http://localhosttt:9764/services/Transaction/end_boxcar"
                  action="urn:end_boxcar">
            <source type="envelope"/>
            <target xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                    xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
         </callout>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="M4" value="*************HITTING Transaction PROXY*************"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

but log is showing `JSESSIONID=null`
and even i tried this properties also no change in log

```
 <property name="setCookieHeader"
                   expression="get-property('transport','Set-Cookie')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
 <property name="setCookieHeader5"
                   expression="get-property('transport','JSESSIONID')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
```

how would i get if i call from CURL the dss operation begin_boxcarring end point  giving like this in header

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6776AC50E31EBFC456CDA1895ACDE0B8; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

but unable to get into synapse how would i get .is there any option for transaction really worried about this future in wso2

Comment: refer this links for referance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135505/wso2dss-box-carring-not-working-in-wso2esb4-8-0/21139656#21139656

Comment: Hi, if you are simply looking for transactions you can use [Transaction Mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Transaction+Mediator)

Comment: thanks for reply transaction mediator not working and dss will handle concurent connection with db where as esb will less performed comparing to dss but wso2esb not supporting for transaction mediator and boxcar in dss how can i handle transaction using wso2 tools